# Is there any advantage of using redux (actions) with axios to get data over getting using just axios?

Tags: reactjs, redux

This might be a silly thing but is bogging me a bit.

I have seen many developers using react redux action to make http calls and get the data and store it globally through reducers even if the data wouldn't be used anywhere else other than the page.

However, the same thing can be done without using the redux thing. Is there any benefits of using react-redux just for this purpose?

Comment: Uniform control over data flow comes to mind. Can you imagine working in a codebase that didn't enforce standardized data requests? If each feature or page that didn't really need to persist data to app state used its own convention of fetching? If later you need to share that same data to another feature/page would require a refactor. Using one single form of fetching data makes it easy to unit test, add new requests, and subscribe new components/features/pages/etc... to the data store.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ofcourse Its reduce server pressure.

The purpose of Redux itself, is to hold our application state. One of the great features of Redux is that we can change our state in a well-defined pattern and it's a pattern that we repeat over and over in our applications.